# CUDA : Might a host method that calls a kernel/cudaMemcpy return before the kernel/memcpy finish?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a method that copies some data to the device, calls multiple kernels each on their own stream, and then calls `cudaMemcpyAsync` for different streams so that they run after their respective kernels.

Since I have read that both kernels and `cudaMemcpyAsync` are launched and run in parallel with host code, might the function I call them in return before these are finished,  or will it only run in parallel with host code in the same function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Might a host method that calls a kernel/cudaMemcpy return before the kernel/memcpy finish?

Yes it might.  If all you do is call kernels and `cudaMemcpyAsync` operations, the cpu function that calls these may finish/return before the operations are complete (even if it is your `main` routine!)

These operations are all *asynchronous*, which means they don't block the CPU thread that calls them.

Even if you have a lot of CPU code that gets run after the kernel calls and `cudaMemcpyAsync` calls, there's no guarantee that the GPU activity will finish (or even start!) unless you use some function that synchronizes host thread with device activity, such as an ordinary `cudaMemcpy` call or a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` call or a `cudaStreamSynchronize()` or other similar calls.

This isn't affected by the functional structure of your cpu/host code.